# Github oauth multiple authorization callback URL

Tags: github, oauth, oauth-2.0

I want to work in my localhost and my live domain, there is any way to insert more then one callback to github oauth settings? How we solve this problem?

[Redirect URLs](https://developer.github.com/v3/oauth/#redirect-urls)

Answer (score 17, accepted):

The bad news is we can't insert more than one callback to GitHub OAuth setting.

Good news is that we can use multiple callback sub-url under our callback url, then you can redirect(proxy) it to any callback url that you want.

for example, if your callback url is: domain.com/auth/github/callback, then the following callback url are all valid:

1. domain.com/auth/github/callback/sub-callback-1
2. domain.com/auth/github/callback/sub-callback-2
3. domain.com/auth/github/callback/sub-callback-3

etc.

After redirect to sub-callback-N with all parameters, then we could jump to any other callback url as you expected.

Comment: My problem is I would like one authorized callback URL to work locally `https://localhost/auth/github/callback` and one to be used in production `https://example.net/auth/github/callback`. Can this be achieved with what you describe above?

Comment: I think so. I believe you can set up a `https://example.net/auth/github/callback-localhost` and then let your server redirect it to `localhost` to archive that.

Comment: Putting some more thoughts into it, I don't think this is a good solution because if I configured my OAuth app for production with `https://example.net/auth/github/callback` it means I have to change the configuration of my web server in production to redirect to `https://localhost/auth/github/callback`. Right? I have proposed another solution below. What do you think?

Comment: Adding a additional redirect url for development is not needed. Since loopback urls are always allowed. See [GitHub OAuth Docs](https://docs.github.com/en/apps/oauth-apps/building-oauth-apps/authorizing-oauth-apps#loopback-redirect-urls). Please note that you have to use `127.0.0.1` or `::1` instead of `localhost`

Answer (score 43):

I solved this issue by creating a dedicated OAuth application on Github for my local development environment. So I have the following 2 OAuth applications:

1. My official OAuth application for production

   - Client ID: `ABC`
   - Client Secret: `123`
   - Authorization callback URL: `https://example.com/api/v1/security/oauth/github/callback`
2. My private OAuth application for development

   - Client ID: `XYZ`
   - Client Secret: `456`
   - Authorization callback URL: `https://localhost/api/v1/security/oauth/github/callback`

When I configure my API in local, I use the ID and secret of the development application (2). And in production I use the ID and secret of my official application (1).

Comment: This is the right way to go. Everything else is just a hack. Also, Github should provide a way to specify multiple callbacks though.

Answer (score 2):

Instead of using localhost, you can modify your hosts file and point your domain to use 127.0.0.1. On a Mac, open the hosts file located under:

```
Computer > Macintosh HD > etc
```

Add the entry for your domain. For example if your domain is mycoolapp.com

```
127.0.0.1 mycoolapp.com
```

Just make sure to comment out this line when you want to test using your production server:

```
#127.0.0.1 mycoolapp.com
```

Using this solution, you don't need to maintain two separate configurations.

Answer (score 2):

[According their doc](https://docs.github.com/en/developers/apps/building-oauth-apps/authorizing-oauth-apps#redirect-urls), you don't need to register localhost redirect URLs, but it just accepts URLs even if it doesn't match the registered one as long as its host part is localhost.