# How to implement/hack two callback URLs for GitHub OAuth

Tags: node.js, express, oauth-2.0, github-api, linkedin-api

I want to be able to `authenticate`(for signing up with GitHub) and `authorize`(for linking GitHub account to an existing account) in separate routes for GitHub OAuth. I handle this with LinkedIn OAuth with two different routes, one that calls `passport.authenticate()` and one that calls `passport.authorize()`. GitHub only allows you to have one callback URL though.

I've found this [post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35942009/github-oauth-multiple-authorization-callback-url) explaining a workaround, but do not know exactly how to implement the answer.

Below is my setup with Linkedin OAuth that works fine.

```
router.get('/auth/linkedin', passport.authenticate('linkedin'));
router.get('/auth/linkedin/callback', passport.authenticate('linkedin', {
  failureRedirect : '/app/#/login'
}), function(req, res){
    res.redirect('/app/#/profile');
});

router.get('/connect/linkedin',
  passport.authorize('linkedin', {
        failureRedirect: '/app/#/login' })
);
router.get('/connect/linkedin/callback',
  passport.authorize('linkedin', {
      successRedirect : '/app/#/profile',
      failureRedirect : '/app/#/login'
  })
);
```

Answer (score 1):

if both urls are on the same domain, port and protocol, you can speciy a URL that is above the ones you want to use, for example:

if your pages are on
`https://example.com/oauth/authorize` and
`https://example.com/oauth/authenticate`

you can set `https://example.com/oauth`as callback URL in github and throw in the redirect_uri parameter in the request to github.

more here:
https://developer.github.com/v3/oauth/#redirect-urls