# I can't set multiple github oauth callback urls?

Tags: github, oauth-2.0, github-api, github-oauth

Now I'm making a Rails app and add github login.
I think I want to try 2 github oauth callback urls for localhost and production environment, but 
there is just one form here.

[github oauth](https://i.stack.imgur.com/f86Ib.png)

I read below article, but I couldn't solve.

How I should do this problem ?

Thanks.

Comment: I forgot to post a referencr url
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35942009/github-oauth-multiple-authorization-callback-url

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Github oauth multiple authorization callback URL](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35942009/github-oauth-multiple-authorization-callback-url)